# Angular Resource get int changing to {}

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

i'm trying to get an int from my API, the factory is as following:

```
factory('Rating', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    var src = config.getValue("api.rating");
    return $resource(src, {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}])
```

And I call it like this:

```
$scope.videoRating = Rating.get({ Vid: $scope.video.Id });
```

but in my template it get's renderd as following `{}` the api is just returning an `int`

```
Rating: {{ videoRating }}
```

Am I doing something wrong? or isn't angular like the int returning?

Comment: Could you please provide the related snippet of your template as well?

Comment: Don't know how this is relevant but added:

Comment: are you saying api is only returning integer as text and not in JSON?  If so, why?

Comment: because my function is `public int Get(string vid)` so I though it is  useless to convert it to a `JToken`

Comment: $resource is for restful services, you need to return some sort of json,atom,xml etc..

Comment: in theory you can have an int returning from an REST service. if that is the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the data the way you're doing it. $scope.videoRating will be a promise not some data you expect it to be.
Here's some copy-paste from the angular docs regarding the $resource module:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123})
    .$promise.then(function(user) {
      $scope.user = user;
    });
```

So basically you need to assign the data to $scope.videoRating after the promise has been resolved.

Comment: Still giving me the same result

Comment: Can you do a console.log() of the data you receive in the then() callback and check if it's what you expect?